# Require Rich Text Editor for Java Web app?

Tags: rte

Can anyone suggest a Rich Text editor with Spell Checking for a Java Web App.
It should be compatible with pictures. For eg. If we copy and paste an image from the MSWord into the editor it should not go out of the editor or the editor should not expand according to the image.

Note : RTE can be paid or open source!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at CKEditor http://ckeditor.com/